# Transfer data from FirebaseMessagingService to Activity using rxjava

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, rx-android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0, rx-java2

I am currently just using `EventBus` to transfer data from FirebaseMessagingService `onMessageReceived` to MainActivity , but this is getting tricky as complexity goes on and what if i get multiple notifications ? on the other hand,

Data transfer is costing 1 extra class and 2 boiler plate function due to EventBus.

So Problem is how to transfer data from FirebaseMessagingService to Activity using Rxjava , and is there any way to convert this whole service to some observables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would still need to `Service` to receive the notifcations. However, you could use a `PublishSubject` to publish items like this:

```
class NotificationsManager {

    private static PublishSubject<Notification> notificationPublisher;

    public PublishSubject<Notification> getPublisher() {
        if (notificationPublisher == null) {
            notificationPublisher = PublishSubject.create();
        }

        return notificationPublisher;
    }

    public Observable<Notification> getNotificationObservable() {
        return getPublisher().asObservable();
    }
}

class FirebaseMessagingService {

    private PublishSubject<Notification> notificationPublisher;

    public void create() {
        notificationPublisher = NotificationsManager.getPublisher()
    }

    public void dataReceived(Notification notification) {
        notificationPublisher.onNext(notification)
    }
}

class MyActivity {

    private Observable<Notification> notificationObservable;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        notificationObservable = NotificationsManager.getNotificationObservable()

        notificationObservable.subscribe(...)
    }
}
```

Edit: expanded the example. Please note this is not the best way to do it, just an example

Comment: I didn't get it , how can you transfer `notificationPublisher` from FMS to activity , are you saying i should make it static in FMS ? , it will leak memory

Comment: You could make a manager class that maintains this `notificationPublisher` and make sure to properly dispose the reference of it in the Service and Actvity

Comment: can you illustrate with some basic example ?

Comment: Added a sample, but have a look into dependency injection & Dagger

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can convert Service for using Observables by using PublishSubject . Just return it as observable by 
subject.asObservable() and pass it new event from onEvent() method by
subject.onNext().
Use Service binding to bind your Service to Activity, and , whithing binding interface, return references to your subjects as observables.

```
PublishSubject<String> eventPipe = PublishSubject.create();

        Observable<String> pipe = eventPipe.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).asObservable();
        // susbcribe to that source
        Subscription s =  pipe.subscribe(value -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Value received: " + value));

        // give next value to source (use it from onEvent())
        eventPipe.onNext("123");

        // stop receiving events (when you disconnect from Service)
        if (s != null && !s.isUnsubscribed()){
            s.unsubscribe();
            s = null;
        }

        // we're disconnected, nothing will be printed out
        eventPipe.onNext("321");
```

Comment: some basic example please for where exactly to use `subject.asObservable()` and why